# Set tolerance for scipy.optimizie.basinhopping using SLSQP method

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to run SLSQP optimization algorithm with basinhopping to solve a non-linear problem. I tried printing the objective function after each iteration and observed that after 5-10 iterations, the values don't change much. I want the algorithm to stop if there is no significant change in the objective function.

I tried using `tol` and `ftol` arguments. They did not help. Looking at other answers in stackoverflow if the `'callback'` argument within `'minimizer_kwargs'` is set to `True`, it should stop that round of iteration. But it doesn't happen.

```
res = optimize.basinhopping(objectivefunc, x0,callback=basinhopping_callback, T=T0, stepsize=stepsize0, 
                            minimizer_kwargs={'method':'SLSQP','bounds': bnds, 'constraints': cons,
                                              'callback' : print_callback,
                                             'options' :{'disp': True,'maxiter':50,'ftol':1e-4}},
                            seed=123456, niter=maxiter,interval=5,take_step=my_take_step)
```

Defining `print_callback` function which should help stop the iterations

```
ftol_local = 1e-2

# Define the consecutive runs threshold
max_runs_below_threshold = 3
num_runs_below_threshold = 0
prev_fun = np.inf
n = 1

def print_callback(xk):
    global num_runs_below_threshold, prev_fun,n
    n+=1
    print(n)
     f_new = objectivefunc(xk)
     print(n,prev_fun,f_new,f_new-prev_fun)
     n+=1
     if np.abs(f_new - prev_fun) <= ftol_local:
         num_runs_below_threshold += 1
      else:
          num_runs_below_threshold = 0
     prev_fun = f_new
     if num_runs_below_threshold >= max_runs_below_threshold:
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

Just for reference and not the issue, providing the `basinhopping_callback` function as well

```
df_iter_basinhopping = pd.DataFrame()
iter1=0

# Define the callback function to add rows to the DataFrame
def basinhopping_callback(x, f, accepted):
    global df_iter_basinhopping,iter1
    
    # Add the row to the DataFrame
    #df_iter_basinhopping = df_iter_basinhopping.append(row_dict, ignore_index=True)
    df_iter_basinhopping = df_iter_basinhopping.append({"f": -f, "accepted": accepted,"x": x}, ignore_index=True)
    iter1+=1
    print(f"Iteration: {iter1} - Function value: {-f}")
```

Any help on how to stop SLSQP optimization when the objective functions does not change a lot?